# CURl not returning an entire page

Tags: php, curl

I am using CURl to retrieve a page for a small search engine project I am working on, but on some pages it's not retrieving the entire page.

The function that I have setup is:

```
public function grabSourceCode($url) {
    // Try and get source code using @file_get_contents
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 50;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'NameBot/0.2');
    $source_code = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $source_code;
  }
```

and I am retrieving the page using:

```
$Crawler->grabSourceCode('https://sedo.com/search/searchresult.php4?keyword=cats&language_output=e&language=e')
```

on [this](http://www.whythink.co.uk/available_domains/july_2008/availabledomains_july_08-1.html) page I get everything, but on [this](https://sedo.com/search/searchresult.php4?keyword=cats&language_output=e&language=e) page, I only get part of the page.

I have tried using `file_get_contents()` but that has the same results.

It seem's to be an issue with dynamic loading of the page, when I run the browser in JavaScript blocking mode it shows the same results as the CURl function.

Is there anyway to do this in PHP, or would I have to look at another language, such as JavaScript?

Thanks, Daniel

Comment: You need to use `selenium` or `phantomjs` (Or similar tool) to scrape websites that load data using ajax

Comment: curl fetches bytes. it doesn't parse those bytes, or execute them. html is no different than gif or a .mp4 to curl. it's all just bytes. therefore any JS code in html you fetch is just a bunch of random text characters, not code.

Comment: @AlonEitan, Thanks, I was going to look into `node.js` as it's server side, so I'll look into those as well :)

Comment: Note: I have found [this](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/) page which allows you to run `PhantomJS` via `PHP`